# How can I set a Certificate for a SOAP Request in .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: asp.net-core, soap

I have imported a WSDL file as a "Connected Service" in .NET Core 3.1.
The WebService requires to use a .p12 certificate.
Unfortunately, I don't know where or how to set the certificate.

This is my current code:

```
BasicHttpsBinding binding = new BasicHttpsBinding();

binding.Name = "basic_ssl_cert";
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;

EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("https://myWebService");

MyWebServiceGeneratedClass service = new MyWebServiceGeneratedClass(binding, address);
```

The `MyWebServiceGeneratedClass` does not offer anything, I could use to set the certificate.

Where or how can I set the certificate with the password?

***UPDATE***
The property `ClientCredentials` is only available on the generated service class but NOT on the generated interface on top of the service class.
As I was programming against the interface, i didn't see the property...

Comment: [This doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication) describes doing this with WsHttpBinding rather than BasicHttpsBinding, as the name suggests Basic bindings are not designed to expose many features and the WS bindings are more feature-rich, but the code sample doesn't do anything with the binding instance that Basic obviously wouldn't have, so both may work (I haven't tried it)

Comment: Re-reading, I didn't spot the first time round that `MyWebServiceGeneratedClass` may not be the same type of client, are you saying this doesn't have a `ClientCredentials` property you can access as in the linked doc?

Comment: I have found my mistake: the property ```ClientCredentials``` is only available on the generated service class and not on the interface. (I was programming against the interface.)
Thanks for your comments - I will change the question accordingly.